# Writing a query in strictly relational algebra (AS IN NOT SQL/MYSQL)

Tags: sql, relational-database, relation, relational-algebra, relational-division

So here are three relations:

**Table Members**

> Members(member_id, name, city, state)

where member_id is the primary key

**Table Borrowed**

> Borrowed(borrow_id, lib_id, member_id)

where borrow_id is the primary key

**Table Libraries**

> Libraries(lib_id, lib_address, lib_city, lib_state)

where lib_id is the primary key

Both lib_id and member_id are foreign keys

So I am trying to write a query that finds all of the member_id of members that have borrowed a book at EVERY library in their city. This means that

```
members.city = libraries.lib_city AND members.state = libraries.lib_state
```

I was thinking about using relational division. For example you have a relation consisting of the member_id's and all of the lib_id where they have borrowed a book. And you divide this by a relation that consists of all of the lib_id in that member's city.

However, I am confused as to how to write this in relational algebraic terms.

In mysql/sql it is very easy but the translation to relational algebra is where I get stuck.

Comment: thank you for editing....but this does not help me figure out the problem at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy is to match the `COUNT(DISTINCT lib_id)` per `member_id` with the total `COUNT(DISTINCT lib_id)` per city.  If the two are equal, the individual has borrowed from every library in his city.

I *think* the following will do the job:

```
SELECT 
  member_id, 
  /* Total libraries borrowed from by member */
  COUNT(DISTINCT Borrowed.lib_id) AS num_libs_borrowed,
  /* Total libs in the member's city */
  COUNT(DISTINCT Libraries.lib_id) AS total_city_libs
FROM 
  Members
  /* JOIN the city between Members & Libraries */
  JOIN Libraries ON Members.city = Libraries.lib_city
  /* JOIN member to borrowed */
  JOIN Borrowed ON Members.member_id = Borrowed.member_id
GROUP BY member_id 
/* If the number of libs borrowed from = the total libs in the city... */
HAVING num_libs_borrowed = total_city_libs
```